# Regex open Li tag inside ul tag

Tags: html, regex

Hi I am try to amke regexp which extract only li tags in ul tags (no ol)

Text:

```
<ul><li>some text</li></ul>
<ol><li>some text</li></lo>
```

Extracted

```
<ul>**<li>**some text</li></ul>
<ol><li>some text</li></lo>
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Regex solution

```
/(?<=<ul>\s*(?:<li>.*?<\/li>\s*)*)<li>.*?<\/li>/gi
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/6b6vu)

If you work in a team and someone else may read your code I advise you to use **Solution 2**. It's more simple and easy to understand by code reading.

#### Solution 2

Do it in 2 steps:

1. Delete all `<ol>...</ol>` nodes;
2. Take all `<li>...</li>` nodes.

*I assume your html is valid and you have no `<li>` outside `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Code example in JavaScript:

```js
let html = `
  <ul>
    <li>take this node 1</li>
    <li>take this node 2</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li>exclude this node</li>
    <li>exclude this node</li>
  </ol>
  <ul>
    <li>take this node 3</li>
    <li>take this node 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li>exclude this node</li>
    <li>exclude this node</li>
  </ol>
`;

let htmlWithoutOl = html.replace(/<ol>.*?<\/ol>/gis, '');
let matches = htmlWithoutOl.matchAll(/<li>.*?<\/li>/gis);
for (const match of matches) {
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```